# SQL Access Sum multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given a table named OrderInfo like below, I would like to sum the quantity and price for each order.

Table:

```
OrderID | Cost | Qty
0001    | 1.1  | 1
0001    | 2.2  | 3
0001    | 3.3  | 2
0002    | 10   | 5
0003    | 4.5  | 1
0003    | 9.9  | 1
...
```

Result:

```
OrderID | Cost | Qty
0001    | 6.6  | 6
0002    | 10   | 5
0003    | 14.4 | 2
...
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT OrderID, Sum(Cost) AS TotCost, Sum(Qty) AS TotQty
FROM OrderInfo
GROUP BY OrderID
```

My end goal is to use the resulting table to get the average of each order, so if there is an easier way to get that without summing cost and qty, then that solution will be nice!

End Goal:

```
OrderID | Average
0001    | 1.1
0002    | 2.00
0003    | 7.2
```

Comment: Avg()..........................But there is nothing wrong with Summing....And I doubt it will be any different/faster under the covers than Sum(Amount)/Sum(Quantity)

Comment: Sum(Cost) / Sum(Qty)

Comment: @MitchWheat How will you write the `AVG` query? Im almost sure will give you different result to `SUM(Cost)/ SUM(Quantity)`

Comment: @ Juan Carlos Oropeza : that will depend on the presence of NULLs

Comment: @MitchWheat Not really. That is why I ask if you did the try. Usually the operations are similar, but different. Something like `(1,10)(5,5)` give you `0.5 vs 0.4`

Comment: Mitch, I tried Avg already, but it didn't work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32031/3

Comment: Mitch, the data does not have any null values. Can you show how you would do the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values you want, just divide your calculations:

```
SELECT OrderID, Sum(Cost) AS TotCost, Sum(Qty) AS TotQty,
       Sum(Cost) / Sum(Qty) AS AvgPerUnit
FROM OrderInfo
GROUP BY OrderID;
```

Comment: I get different values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32031/2

Comment: what value you expect?

Comment: How can I have SumCost and SumQty columns?

Comment: @Ali -- Based on your fiddle (thanks), the problem is you're using a `float` vs a `decimal`.  You should be using a `decimal` -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f308/1 .  If that's not an option, cast your values as decimal instead (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32031/4)...